# Android, I am not able to get string from a sqlite query

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Find the below code:

```
Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT desc FROM DefectTablemain where id='defVal'", null);
c1.getString(0).toString(); // This line s breaking
```

`if(c1 != null) {
    c1.moveToFirst();
    String ch= c1.getColumnName(0);
    c1.getColumnIndex(ch);
    c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(ch));
}`

in this the last line is breaking.

Comment: "This line is breaking" - Breaking how? You need to be specific as to what is happening before anyone can help you!

Comment: check whether your cursor is null or not

Comment: Move to the cursor's first row:

Comment: any errors? if yes please post the logcat.. are you sure your table has data in it ?

Comment: Yes im able to see the data when I run select query for all data

Answer (score 2):

You are not checking whether cursor is `null` or not..and it contains any data or not..check like this..

```
if (c1!=null) {
        if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
            //here get the your data..
            c1.getString(0).toString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Move to the cursor's first row:

```
 if (c1 != null)
{
    if (c1.moveToFirst())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before starting to get data from cursor you need to make cursor to first position

```
    Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT desc FROM DefectTablemain where id='defVal'", null);
    c1.moveToFirst();
    c1.getString(0).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT desc FROM DefectTablemain where id='defVal'", null);
if(c1!=null)  {     
 c1.moveToFirst();
        c1.getString(0).toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getDesc()
{

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT desc FROM DefectTablemain where id='defVal' ", null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();

    String desc ="";
    if(count!=0)
    {
        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            desc =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("desc"));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        desc ="NA";
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return desc ; 
}
```

Comment: please approve if my answer is help you

Answer (score 0):

Check c1.moveToFirst() is successfull or not

```
if(c1.moveToFirst()) {
    c1.getString(0);
```

}

Cursor.moveToFirst() will return false if cursor is empty.[enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29)